# Aggregating a set of rows into single result in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am converting a schema from Postgres to MySQL and am stumped at an apparent lack of a built-in function to aggregate a set of results, returned by a (sub) query, similar e.g. to Postgres's string_agg(). Specifically, assume a table `t` with 3 rows:

```
COL
"x"
"y"
"z"
```

In Postgres, `SELECT string_agg(col, ',') FROM t` will return a single row result with all `COL` values concatenated with the specified delimiter, i.e. the string `x,y,z`. How can I accomplish this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Group_Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate different row values separated by a delimiter string (Default is comma (`,`))

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col)
FROM t
```

Extended Version can be:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT col 
                    ORDER BY col ASC
                    SEPARATOR ';') 
FROM t
```

Above will pick only unique value of `col` and concatenate by semi-colon delimiter (`;`, instead of comma) and `col` values will be in Ascending order.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table t (col varchar(2));
insert into t values('x'),('y'),('z');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col) FROM t;

| GROUP_CONCAT(col) |
| ----------------- |
| x,y,z             |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPoNj7fdmZJFxQMDKpJ6UG/0)